# Summation of arithmetic-geometric series of higher order

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

There is a closed formula for the summation of arithmetic-geometric series:

$\sum_{x=1}^{+\infty }(ax+b)r^x=\frac{(a+b)r-br^2}{(1-r)^2}$

when $-1<r<1$

But consider:

$\sum_{x=1}^{+\infty }(ax^2+bx+c)r^x$

I would call this "*(second order arithmetic)-geometric*". There is something known about this type of series?, i mean something like a closed formula as in the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,
$$ r\frac{d}{dr} \sum_{x=1}^\infty x^n r^x
= r \sum_{x=1}^\infty x^n \frac{d}{dr} r^x
= r \sum_{x=1}^\infty x^{n+1} r^{x-1}
= \sum_{x=1}^\infty x^{n+1} r^x $$
So if you have a closed form for $\sum_{x=1}^\infty x^n r^x$ you can get one for $\sum_{x=1}^\infty x^{n+1} r^x$.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see how this helps. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: You have a closed form for $\sum_{x=1}^\infty xr^x$; use this method to get one for $\sum_{x=1}^\infty x^2r^x$.  Then your problem is solved.

Comment: Can you please point to a resource where such problems are discussed in detail.

Comment: @emmy : The standard resource is the book [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html), by Herbert S. Wilf.